# In Adobe Illustrator CS3, how can I fill particular parts of non-objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In Adobe Illustrator CS3, how can I fill just the boxes of a plot with color? The plot displays as just one object in Illustrator, so it is not as simple as selecting the box object and filling it.

Comment: One raster object or one vector object? There is a world of difference. If it's vector AICS3 has the Live Paint Bucket Tool.

Comment: One vector object.

Comment: @Scott when I try the Live Paint Bucket Tool, I get the following: `The selection contains objects that cannot be converted. Paint groups can only contain paths and compound paths. Clipping paths are not allowed.` How can I get around this?

Comment: Well, you could release the clipping paths (Object Menu) but honestly, without seeing the file it's very difficult to give any direction.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion: no success. If you 'Save Image As' of the figure I've included, that should serve as a surrogate.

Comment: No.. the image in this post is a raster image, not a vector image. There's a difference. If your posted image matches the image you are working with, then you do not have a vector file. Just because you open an image with Illustrator, it does not make it a vector image.

Comment: Ok, so if it's raster, how can I do this?

Comment: Honestly for something that simply, grab the pen tool and draw the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Find the paths you want to fill in the layers panel. That's much easy than stumbling around with the selection tools on the artboard. In some cases it's easier to just dupe the path in the layers panel (opt-drag) and then fill it.